# Using array members during array initialization in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Is it legal to do the following in C++:

```
const T array[3]{
  **some expression**,
  **another expression**,
  T{ 1 } - array[0] - array[1]
};
```

In other words: will the 3rd element always be initialized to `1 - **some expression** - **another expression**`?

Answer (score 2):

initializer list uses left to right evaluation, **but** it is evaluated before the initialization of array.

> will the 3rd element always be initialized to 1 - **some expression** - **another expression**?

No, and you have even UB with `T{ 1 } - array[0] - array[1]`.